# Typescript issue with Sequelize that I can't solve

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

```
export const bookDemo = async () => {
  const Book = sequelize.define(
    "Book",
    {
      bookKey: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      userKey: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      bookTitle: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      dateAdded: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
      },
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true, // enforces that table name = model name
    }
  );

  // sync method creates table
  await Book.sync({ force: true });
  console.log("INFO: book table (re)created!");

  const aBook1 = await Book.create({ bookTitle: "A Good One", userKey: 1 });

  const aBook2 = await Book.create({
    bookTitle: "Another Good One",
    userKey: 1,
  });

  aBook2.set({ bookTitle: "Another Great One" });
  aBook2.save();

  interface BookModel {
    bookKey: Number;
    userKey: Number;
    bookTitle: String;
    dateAdded: Date;
  }

  const books = await Book.findAll();
  books.map((book: Model<BookModel>) => console.log(book.bookTitle));
};
```

I get an error on book.bookTitle.
The error is -- Property 'bookTitle' does not exist on type 'Model'.ts(2339).

I've tried adding and removing the BookModel to book without success.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of `sequelize` are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 6.28.0.

Answer (score 1):

*sequelize: v6.28.0*, there is a good TypeScript example in official documentation [Usage of Sequelize#define](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/#usage-of-sequelizedefine). You don't need to explicitly specify the type for `book` in `.map` function, and TS will automatically infer the type.

Try:

```
import {
  CreationOptional,
  DataTypes,
  InferAttributes,
  InferCreationAttributes,
  Model,
  Sequelize,
} from 'sequelize';

export const bookDemo = async () => {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql://root:asd123@localhost:3306/mydb');
  interface BookModel
    extends Model<
      InferAttributes<BookModel>,
      InferCreationAttributes<BookModel>
    > {
    bookKey: CreationOptional<number>;
    userKey: number;
    bookTitle: string;
    dateAdded: CreationOptional<number>;
  }

  const Book = sequelize.define<BookModel>(
    'Book',
    {
      bookKey: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      userKey: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      bookTitle: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      dateAdded: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
      },
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true, // enforces that table name = model name
    }
  );

  // sync method creates table
  await Book.sync({ force: true });
  console.log('INFO: book table (re)created!');

  const aBook1 = await Book.create({ bookTitle: 'A Good One', userKey: 1 });
  const aBook2 = await Book.create({
    bookTitle: 'Another Good One',
    userKey: 1,
  });
  aBook2.set({ bookTitle: 'Another Great One' });
  aBook2.save();

  const books = await Book.findAll();
  books.map((book) => console.log(book.bookTitle));
};
```